# Getting TTPickerTextField to work?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I am crossposting this in the groups.google because I find it so very difficult to get answers on Three20

I can see from other posts that it is hard getting some newbie/starter help on Three20, but it is really hard to get started with Three20 with the lack of documentation and examples, so I will try :) Bear with me, I am just trying to get started with this very nice library.

I have created a TTPickerTextField and set its dataSource property to a instance of the MockSearchDataSource from the examples to get something up and running that I can drill down into. So I have some code like this:

TTPickerTextField *pickerField = [[TTPickerTextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; 
pickerField.dataSource = [[[MockSearchDataSource alloc] init] autorelease]; 
[self.view addSubview:pickerField];

The TTPickerTextField gets displayed and I can enter text into the field, but it does not display any of the persons in my MockSearchDataSource. I have tried to drill into the TTMessageController code to see if I can figure out what I need to do, but I can not figure it out.

Could someone please step up and help me here? I really have tried my best to work this out my self, but I just dont have a clue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your MockSearchDataSource returns the correct dataSource as it has to inherit from `TTTableViewDataSource`:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) id<TTTableViewDataSource> dataSource;
```